# python modify builtin string functions

Tags: string, python-2.7, split, built-in

is it possible in Python to modify, or - at least - deny of execution builtin functions? I need, for **educational** purpose, to make sure that *strings split* is unavailable.

For example, I want, if call

```
'a,b,c'.split(',')
```

to throw exception or be returned inputed string.

I want to force someone to write own version of that function. Is it possible? 

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Built-in types (str in your case) and methods cannot be monkey-patched, since they are implemented in C (for cpython implementation).

However, you can define a subclass and redefine the method:

```
>>> class Mystr(str):
...     def split(self, *args):
...             raise Exception("Split is not defined")
... 
>>> Mystr("test").split(",")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in split
Exception: Split is not defined
```

Comment: Maybe `def split(self, *args):` so that it will accept the default of no arguments? Otherwise, it will throw an exception about the number of arguments.

Comment: Yes, I thought a little about that way. Thanks for example, maybe I'll have to use that!